# How to select record from same column but different value

Tags: mysql

I want to select a record from below table I have tried with this query

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = 'rating_average' and meta_key='rating_counter'
```

Which is not working.

if I select with this then working

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = 'rating_average'
```

I want both `meta_key = 'rating_average' and meta_key='rating_counter'`

[image]

Comment: Use `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: But i want both why i use OR Please @1000111

Comment: `meta_key` cannot be `rating_average` and `rating_counter` at the same time. Let's say in English : I want records if `meta_key` is either `rating_average` or `rating_counter`. Look we used `OR`. If you use `and` this means both conditions should be met at the same time. @SajidAnwar

Comment: `meta_key = 'rating_average' and meta_key='rating_counter' ` are not in same record that's why you can not see results. No issue with query, query is fine.
The way you are thinking is not possible with `AND`, you can use `OR` to get your desired results.

Comment: Thanks @UsmanMaqbool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired output using below methods

**1) Using OR**

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE meta_key = 'rating_average' OR meta_key='rating_counter';
```

**2) Using IN**

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE meta_key IN ('rating_average', 'rating_counter');
```

**3) Using UNION**

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE meta_key = 'rating_average' 
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE meta_key = 'rating_counter';
```

Comment: Thank you much. Wow union keyword which is new for me. I will study about this today. Thanks

Comment: I would not recommend `UNION` for this scenario, `IN` is the best approach for this case. Because using UNION you'll have to add multiple queries for simple search on a same column.

Answer (score 2):

You want `OR`, but a more typical way of doing this uses `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE meta_key IN ('rating_average', 'rating_counter');
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key IN ('rating_average', 'rating_counter') and post_id IN(".$matches.") and  meta_value >= 10 ORDER BY meta_value desc LIMIT 1

Comment: I just add my query   meta_value >= 10 this will be corrrect? @gordan

Comment: concise and perfect no need to say anything to @Gordon you are boss

Answer (score 1):

Try **IN** Query:

```
`SELECT * 
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE meta_key IN ('rating_average','rating_counter')
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key IN ('rating_average', 'rating_counter') and post_id IN(".$matches.") and meta_value >= 10 ORDER BY meta_value desc LIMIT 1

Comment: I just add my query meta_value >= 10 this will be corrrect?@sandip-patel

Comment: SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE  meta_key IN ('rating_average', 'rating_counter') and  post_id IN(1053,1067) and  meta_value >= 0  ORDER BY meta_value desc limit 1

Comment: Downvote because the same query was already posted before. Duplicate answers are not appreciable.

Comment: No Please remove your downvote this answer was on second numbe.r and you can check it comment this was the first person which told me that use IN statement @Shaharyar

Comment: And you know that accepted answer always goto to top although if they last answer. @Shaharyar

Comment: @Sajid Anwar : Thanks for your support

Comment: **Gordon Linoff** answered first with this approach. I was watching actually.